# Ubuntu 16.04 with 20.04 kernel?

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, kernel, ros

Working with ROS gets me stuck on 16.04, only because ROS Kinetics packages my robots work with.

Would it be possible to have newer kernel and the old ubuntu, without effecting ROS at all?

Comment: It might be *possible*, but it also might not. Nobody has tested such a configuration, and we are unlikely to provide support it.

Comment: Up to about 5 months ago, I used to use the newest mainline kernels on my old 16.04 test server all the time. However, I have now (finally) upgraded that server. The only issue that came up of recent was that kernels are now compressed via a method not supported with 16.04, so one needs to re-compile with that config setting changed. (I'll find the details if needed.)

Comment: @DougSmythies  
This sounds like a solution. Do you think ROS may run smoothly on it?

Comment: I don't know about ROS. the compression has to be changed from LZ4 to GZIP.